# How to make a multiple input block entity?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am coding a minecraft mod and I have recently been trying to make a custom block entity. My problem is relatively simple; how would I make a block entity that has multiple input slots? I have everything else done, I am just not sure how to get the public boolean matches to work.

```
public class AltarOfEssenceRecipe implements Recipe<SimpleContainer> {
private final ResourceLocation id;
private final ItemStack output;
private final NonNullList<Ingredient> recipeItems;

public AltarOfEssenceRecipe(ResourceLocation id, ItemStack output,
                            NonNullList<Ingredient> recipeItems) {
    this.id = id;
    this.output = output;
    this.recipeItems = recipeItems;
}


 @Override
public boolean matches(SimpleContainer pContainer, Level pLevel) {
    if(pLevel.isClientSide()) {
        return false;
    }

    return recipeItems.get(0).test(pContainer.getItem(1));
}
```

I understand that the current code above is for when there is only one input slot, but mine has four. How could I approach this?

The code above is only for one slot, which obviously will not work with my four-input block entity.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: that's not javascript, looks more like Java

Comment: What is the type of `recipeItems`? `List<Predicate>`? Also, why is it validating the first element there against the second item in `pContainer`? I understand what the code is doing, but it would help to know **why** it has to do it that way (or what is supposed to be doing).

Comment: What "input slots" are you talking about? It sounds like you're using some kind of library/framework/tool that has those, but you don't mention what it is. (Edit: apparently [it's Minecraft](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/117772-how-to-make-a-multiple-input-block-entity/), would have helped if you had mentioned that, Nathan!)

Comment: Oh my goodness, how did I not provide information that simple? I am so sorry!

Comment: I have updated the post. I deeply apologize for that; hope this provides enough information!